# Navigation stack not publishing Obstacles & inflation obstacles details

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

I am trying to use navigation stack with static map fed to it. Currently i am feeding LaseScan data through Kinect and sonar sensors. When triggering the navigation launch file and observing the same in rviz i can see the global and local path seems to be getting created but cant see and information related to the obstacles and inflation obstacles. Going through the tutorial this is supposed to be published on /local_costmap/inflated_obstacles and /local_costmap/obstacles respectively.

Instead of these topics i can see topics like
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_updates
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/footprint_stamped
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer_footprint/parameter_updates

But these topics cannot be monitored in RVIZ as the data type doesn't match with nav_msgs/GridCells.

My launch file looks like below

`

`

costmap_common_params.yaml

max_obstacle_height: 0.80
obstacle_range: 1
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[-0.3,-0.3],[-0.3,0.3],[0.45,0.3], [0.45,-0.3]]

inflation_radius: 0.55

obstacles:
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor sonar_scan_1 sonar_scan_2 sonar_scan_3 sonar_scan_4

#laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: camera_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}

laser_scan_sensor: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: 0.05, max_obstacle_height: 0.5}
sonar_scan_sensor: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: sonar_scan_1, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: 0., max_obstacle_height: 0.15}
sonar_scan_sensor: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: sonar_scan_2, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: 0., max_obstacle_height: 0.15}
sonar_scan_sensor: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: sonar_scan_3, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: 0., max_obstacle_height: 0.15}
sonar_scan_sensor: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: sonar_scan_4, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: 0., max_obstacle_height: 0.15}

Thanks in Advance,
Nithin G

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196976/navigation-stack-not-publishing-obstacles-&-inflation-obstacles-details/) by [Nithin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20057/nithin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-11-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nithin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20057/nithin/) on 2014-11-12**:
Does anyone have idea on this? This is still an issue. Cant see topics for obstacles and inflated obstacles.
In hydro is it published on different topic or something?

Thanks,
Nithin

**Comment by [rem1968](https://answers.ros.org/users/29519/rem1968/) on 2017-02-28**:
Hi Nithin,  did you ever get this resolved?  I am having the same problem.  I am working on ROS Indigo.  Thanks, Eric

**Comment by [ROOBBE](https://answers.ros.org/users/32664/roobbe/) on 2018-03-26**:
I meet this problem too
how to solve it?

**Comment by [pk99](https://answers.ros.org/users/73613/pk99/) on 2021-04-23**:
How did you solve this problem? Also is /scan topics or the sensor stream data getting published to move_base. I'm asking cause you haven't posted a rqt_graph screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just got my navigation stack up and running and had much the same issue.

The [RViz with Navigation Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack) does not seem to be up to date with the verion of RViz or gmapping that I am using, as the video has you adding Grid Cells for displaying obstacles, costmaps, and inflation data.

The problem is that Grid Cells utilizes `nav_msgs::GridCells` messages and the topics which publish obstacle, costmap, and inflation data are `nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid` messages.

The way to display this information is to add two **Map** displays.  One with the topic `/move_base/local_costmap/costmap` and the other with `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap`.

I hope this helps.  If it does not, please let me know and we will try to get you through this.

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-09-27**:
I am also facing the same problem as discussed above by @Nithin and may be due to this problem my robot is not able to detect obstacles while reaching its navigation goal. Also by adding two Map displays as mentioned by you does not solve the problem. Can you suggest me what else should I do?

**Comment by [charlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/4007/charlie/) on 2019-04-28**:
I added the maps as described above and the topics  - the /move_base/local_costmap/costmap does seem to infate the region around the laserscan data in the local map region. It does so on both sides of the laser data. I have not validated if it impacts the actual navigation.

**Comment by [yhw](https://answers.ros.org/users/56285/yhw/) on 2020-06-30**:
I can't see why "costmap" and "obstacles" are the same thing. Costmap is an occupancy grid, which is built on the probability computed from the map prior and observations. While "obstacles" (and "inflated obstacles") should be the immediate observation (with inflation) from the scans.

**Comment by [pk99](https://answers.ros.org/users/73613/pk99/) on 2021-04-23**:
@sealguy77 I did the same thing which you suggested but it's not working for me. Also in my rqt_graph, the connection between /scan and /move_base is missing. Is there any obvious solution for this?